# Haskell Alternating Casing in Strings

Tags: haskell

I need to use the functions from `Data.Char` in order to create a function called `camelcaser`, which does what sounds like it does: uppercases and lowercases every letter in the pattern upper→lower→upper→lower.

I've attempted to use `lexLitChar`, to pull out an element then uppercase it, skip the next element until the entire string is completed. I also feel like this could be done with recursion but the type conversions seemed too difficult.

What I was going to do: `String -> [(char,string)] -> [char,(char,string)] -> [char] -> String`

```
camelcaser str = foldr f "" str
    where f x y           = (LexLit x) ++ y
          LexLit    x     = Uppercase (lexlitChar x)
          Uppercase (y,z) = toUpper y
```

I'm kind of stumped on where I'm going with this, anyone care to direct me in the correct path?

Comment: You know you can't give functions names that start with capital letters, right?

Comment: How should the function handle non-letters in the input string?

Answer (score 6):

Well, if the resulting string is supposed to alternate between uppercase & lowercase, then you can just take the characters of the string two at a time: uppercase the first one, lowercase the second one, and then take the next pair.  For example:

```
camelcaser (a:b:str) = toUpper a : toLower b : camelcaser str
```

You still need to work out how to handle strings of fewer than two characters, but that should be easy, and this answer has already gone past the basic nudging hint that I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility. Maybe you can have some fun trying to figure out how it works.

```
camelCaser = map (\(i,c) -> if even i then toUpper c else toLower c) . zip [0..]
```

Comment: To golf a little further, `zipWith ($) (cycle [toUpper, toLower])`